# How should I know what dependency to add for different views?

Tags: android, dependencies

When I want to add different views to my Android Studio project, how should I know what dependency to add?

For example, if I want to use `cardView` I should add `implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:29.0.0'` and if I use `TabLayout` I need to add `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'`, and I know that from tutorials.

But if I look for example in [the official documentry of `CardView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/cardview/widget/CardView), how could I have understaood by myself that the required dependency is the one  I mentioned?

Comment: "if I want to use cardView I should add implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:29.0.0'" -- you should use the latest version [of `androidx.cardview:cardview`](https://androidx.tech/artifacts/cardview/cardview/). "But if I look for example in the official documentry of CardView, how could I have understaood by myself that the required dependency is the one I mentioned?" -- you can't. They had that information in the JavaDocs for a while but dropped it. I'm looking to add some stuff for that in [the AndroidX Tech site](https://androidx.tech/) later this year.

Answer (score 0):

Well, its sort of impossible to know all the dependencies to be added in the project. The best way to know the right requirements is by checking with the developers' website.

You can check the below mentioned link for your reference.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/cardview

Answer (score 0):

I Recommend That Grab the Latest Version of the Library you Wanna Use

> https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/artifact-mappings

//This is the list of libraries

> https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/versions

//This is the list of libraries version

Comment: I don't quite understand. If I want to use `CardView` for example, I look at the **first** link and see the dependency. What does the **second** link use for (in the context of the question)?

Comment: hmm if you insist keep to use old library then, you need to search the library you wanna use and find the version of it one by one in Developer.android.com